# How can change my Ubuntu One profile and Ubuntu developer profile email address?

Tags: ubuntu-one, email

How can change my Ubuntu profile and Ubuntu developer profile email address?

I have a Profile email that soon cease to exist and want replace it.

I created an Ubuntu Phone developer account but auto filled in the email that Ubuntu One has - this in a few weeks I will cease to have access to - how can I change both emails?

Probably if change main profile it will change developer profile?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you mean by "developer profile" (perhaps give a link to it?). Right now no one is really sure what you mean by that..

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add a new email, and change the default on your Ubuntu One Single Sign On.

1. Go to https://login.ubuntu.com/ and login with your current e-mail and password.
2. Under **Personal Details** click on *Manage email address:*

   [image]
3. Enter in a new email address in this field:

   [image]
4. Verify your new email address, by following the instructions they send to that email.
5. Under "Preferred email address" you should now be able to select your new email.

Since your developer account uses the same Ubuntu One SSO, It should pick up on the settings, otherwise the field is unchangeable from there:

[image]

However you can change the e-mail you use for receiving pay-pal payments under "My Account":

[image]

Comment: I thought Ubuntu cancelled "Ubuntu One"? Did they bring it back or am I missing something?

Comment: @Johnn the file sharing service, yes. but "Ubuntu One" was more than just that service - it also served credentials for signing in that are still used for the developer site. This is called "Ubuntu One SSO" "One account to log into everything Ubuntu"

Comment: all right, sorry thanks for clearing that up for me!